# Process got coredumped with sgno 11, no segfault record in dmesg

Tags: segmentation-fault, dmesg

I have a process running on linux docker handling network requests.It got core dumped with signo 11 and generated the core dump file.But I can't see the segfault message in dmesg command.What is the possible reason?